# Better/faster way to read from Serial1 in Arduino Lonardo?

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I would be interested on knowing the faster or better way to read the reply to a command that I send towards one of my serial interfaces (Serial1 in Lonardo platform). So far I have been using as beneath, is there any other better way to read the output from that Serial1?

Thanks in advance,

regards

```
Serial1.print(dataToBeTx);
Serial.print(text + dataToBeTx);
delay(4000);
while (Serial1.available()) Serial.write(Serial1.read());
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple different ways you could handle this, both allowing you to avoid a long `delay(XXXX)` statement. These two, in my experience, are generally the most common, both allowing you to continue executing code when the expected data is received, instead of delaying.

- Using Arduino's [SerialEvent](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SerialEvent) API, which is called when new serial data is ready. You could then determine what to do with the received data.
- Using the [Serial1.readBytes](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/ReadBytes) call, which allows you to specify a set amount of bytes to read, and combined with [Serial1.setTimeout](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/SetTimeout) allow you to set a maximum time to wait for those bytes, in case serial data is not received.